# Turing-completeness of affine programs

Tags: computability, turing-completeness

Are unguarded affine programs Turing-Complete?
Are affine programs with affine guards Turing-Complete?

Unguarded program: all branches are taken

Affine program: only assignments like $x:=x_1+5x_2-x_3+4 $(Affine equations as right hand)

Affine guards: all conditional branches have only affine guards, for instance $x_1+x_2-3x_3>2$

Comment: Can you define in more detail what is an "unguarded affine program" as well as what is a "guarded affine program"? These are not concepts I am familiar with, and I suspect many others are also not familiar with them.

Comment: I have corrected. thank you for the suggestion

Comment: What would it mean for affine programs to be Turing-complete? That is, what sort of functions are you trying to compute? What is the input, and what is the output?

Comment: We may consider as semantic a function from state to state, and as output a particular variable (not present in the input). We may consider only computer representable types, and as computable I mean all functions computed by a Turing machine. I have noticed that there isn't too much literature about Turing-completeness of programming languages.

Comment: If the programming language does not support recursion, then it is not Turing Complete. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) says: 
"Most computer programming languages support recursion by allowing a function to call itself from within its own code. Some functional programming languages do not define any looping constructs but rely solely on recursion to repeatedly call code. It is proved in computability theory that these recursive-only languages are Turing complete; [...]"

Comment: Can you clarify what constructs you allow to appear in programs?  Do you allow while loops, or only straight-line code?  Are the $x$'s integers, integers modulo $2^{32}$, or something else?